# Testing Spring Boot Authentication Token & CSRF Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

I've configured my SpringBoot application to authenticated with an auth token and CSRF token:

```
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/**")
  .hasRole(/**/)
  .and()
  .csrf()
  .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new NoAntPathRequestMatcher(new String[]{"/login"}))
  .and()
  .httpBasic()
  .and()
  .addFilterAfter(new CsrfGrantingFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
```

This means that I can use curl to get the auth token and csrf token:

```
curl -s -v -X POST "http://localhost:8088/login" -u<username>:<password> | jq .

...
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< csrf-token: <token>
< X-Application-Context: application:dev:8088
< x-auth-token: <token>
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
...
```

And then use them to call other methods on the service:

```
curl -s -v -X GET "http://localhost:8088/users" -H "x-auth-token: <token>" -H "X-CSRF-TOKEN: <token>" | jq .
```

This works exactly as intended, but I want to write an automated test in SpringBoot to do the same. I can get the csrf tocken:

```
 MvcResult mvcResult =
                mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful()).andReturn();

MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
final String csrf = response.getHeader("csrf-token");
final String authToken = response.getHeader("x-auth-token");
System.out.println(csrf);
System.out.println(authToken);
```

But not the auth token, I just get null. I can plug the csrf token into the subsequent call:

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users").header("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrf)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful()).andReturn();
```

But of course it fails to authenticate. Any suggestions on how I might make this work?

Comment: Instead of doing it using mock MVC, I would suggest you to use Mockito framework.

Comment: The code which makes the mock request is missing the username/password fields.